# Showing that the dihedral group $D_n = \{a^i b^j \mid 0 <i <6, \ 0 <j< 2 \}$ quotiented by $\langle a^k \rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, quotient-group

Consider the dihedral group $D_n = \{a^i b^j \mid 0 \leq i <6, \ 0 \leq j< 2 \}$  where  $a^n = b^2 = 1$ , and  $a b =b a ^{-1}$. For any divisor $k$ of $n$ show that

$$\langle a^k\rangle\triangleleft D_n \text{ and } D_n/\left \langle a^k \right \rangle\cong D_k $$

**Answer:**

From the definition $ D_n = \{a^i b^j \mid 0 \leq i <6, \ 0 \leq j< 2 \} $  , it is clear that $n=6$.

So we are dealing with $ D_6 \ $.

Now the divisors of $6$  are $ 1, \ 2, \ 3, \ 6 $.

So the subgroups are

$$ \langle a\rangle , \ \langle a^2\rangle , \ \langle a^3\rangle ,  \ \langle a^6\rangle $$

Further,

$$ \langle a\rangle =\{1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5 \}, $$

$$\langle a^2\rangle =\{1, a^2,a^4\}, $$

$$ \langle a^3\rangle =\{1,a^3 \}, \\ \langle a^6\rangle =\{1\} $$

Now, $|D_6|=12$

Then,

$$ \frac{|D_6|}{|\langle a\rangle|}=\frac{12} 6 = 2, $$ So the index $ [D_6 : \langle a\rangle ]=2.$

Hence $\langle a\rangle $ is a normal subgroup of $D_6$.

**But I am unable to prove** $D_n /\langle a^k\rangle \cong D_k \ $ . **Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 2):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}$Let us say

$$D_r = \langle a_r, b_r \mid a_r^r = 1, b_r^2 = 1, a_rb_r = b_ra_r^{-1} \rangle. $$

The subscript $r$ lets us distinguish between elements of $D_n$ and $D_k$.

Let $\wt x$ denote the image of $x \in D_n$ modulo $\langle a^k \rangle$. Then

- $\wt{a_n}^k = 1$
- $\wt{b_n}^2 = 1$
- $\wt{a_n}\wt{b_n} = \wt{b_n}\wt{a_n}^{-1}$

This allows us to say that the map $D_k \to D_n / \langle a^k \rangle$ defined by

$$ a_k \mapsto \wt{a_n} \text{ and } b_k \mapsto \wt{b_2} $$

is a surjective homomorphism (check this). But $|D_k| = 2k = |D_n / \langle a^k \rangle|$, so this has to be an isomorphism.

---

Your proof that $\langle a^k \rangle$ is normal isn't a proof of the intended statement. If there was a $6$ in your assignment, that's a typo and should be an $n$. So you can't assume $n = 6$. You are also assuming that $k = 1$, which isn't general enough.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Your proof is wrong because you have assumed $ a_r b_r=b_ra_r \ $ , which is not true and not given .remember $ D_r \ $ is a dihedral group , so it is not commutative.

Comment: It should be $ a_r b_r =b_r^{-1} a_r \ $

Comment: @mabmath It's not wrong, just a typo. I'm used to writing simply $(a_rb_r)^2 = 1$.